# Typings: 'typings search' finds a package, but 'typings install' fails

Tags: typescript, npm

I'm trying to install the Google Auth2 typings with 'typings':

```
> typings search gapi.auth2
```

returns

```
NAME       SOURCE HOMEPAGE                                            DESCRIPTION VERSIONS UPDATED
gapi.auth2 dt     https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/             1        2016-03-19T05:16:41.000Z
```

but then

```
> typings install gapi.auth2
```

fails:

```
typings ERR! message Unable to find "gapi.auth2" ("npm") in the registry. Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you want contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/gapi.auth2/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200
```

I don't understand why that is happening, I mean, it *does* find the package, no? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
typings install dt~gapi.auth2 --global
```

so the key is the prefix `dt~` which indicates the package source (*definitely typed*, in this case) - and which can be seen in the `search` output as well.

Answer (score 0):

To install typings of required package use --ambient --save like

```
typings install packageName --ambient --save
```

--save saves it inside typings.json for future easy installation and to know more about ambient refer [--ambient explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953848/what-are-ambient-typings-in-the-typescript-typings-tool)

To install gapi.auth2 use

```
typings install gapi.auth2 --ambient --save
```

Answer (score 0):

In typescript 2 you can search here: http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

Then you can use npm to install: `npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2`

And add `typeRoots` in you tsconfig.json:

`"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types"
  ],`

[More info here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)