# DefinitelyTyped: What does 'export = _;' means

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.8, definitelytyped

I'm trying to use angular-material with a ng-metadata project and I run into some issues.

I use DefinitelyTyped for angular material and the first lines are:

```
declare module 'angular-material' {
  var _: string;
  export = _;
}
```

In my main.ts I try to `import { ngMaterial } from 'angular-material';`

then `bootstrap( AppComponent, [ 'ngMaterial' ] );` but all I got is:

```
Error:(3, 10) TS2305: Module ''angular-material'' has no exported member 'ngMaterial'.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Try a plain `import 'angular-material';`. Explanation: you are not actually needing anything from the *ES2015/TS* module; you just want to run it for its side-effects, which are placing the `ngMaterial` *Angular* module into Angular DI namespace.

Comment: Do that and then you can also import singular elements of the definition using for example `import IBottomSheetService = angular.material.IBottomSheetService;`

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'm missing something, but how can I use things like `md-toolbar` in the html templates. With your plain import I dont get errors but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When being used through ES6 or TypeScript, a common pattern that Angular modules follow is that they'll use their name as the default export. For example, one of the modules in my application looks like this:

```
const session = angular.module("smSession", [])
    .service("session", SessionService)
    .component("smLogin", Login)
    .config(routes)
    .run(loginRedirect);

export default session.name;
```

The reasoning behind this is that it makes the syntax for declaring an Angular module's dependencies cleaner; for example:

```
import angular from "angular";
import ngAnimate from "angular-animate";
import ngMaterial from "angular-material";
import uiRouter from "angular-ui-router";

let module = angular.module("myApp", [ ngAnimate, ngMaterial, uiRouter ]);
```

If they instead exported the entire module, you'd have to do this:

```
let module = angular.module("myApp", [ ngAnimate.name, ngMaterial.name, uiRouter.name ]);
```

So this is why the main module declaration for `angular-material` looks like it does - they're simply representing the fact that all you can import from the package is that one string representing the module's name. The rest of the type definitions are [ambient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953848/what-are-ambient-typings-in-the-typescript-typings-tool) - you can just use the `angular.material` namespace anywhere in your application without having to do an import.

EDIT: To clarify, here's the actual source of [the file that gets imported when you import ngMaterial](https://npmcdn.com/angular-material@1.1.0-rc.5):

```
// Should already be required, here for clarity
require('angular');

// Load Angular and dependent libs
require('angular-animate');
require('angular-aria');

// Now load Angular Material
require('./angular-material');

// Export namespace
module.exports = 'ngMaterial';
```

Notice that `require('./angular-material')` doesn't return anything - that import effectively just runs the file that sets up the Angular module behind the scenes (effectively the same sort of code as in my examples). The only thing being exported from the module is the name.

Comment: Ok, so what you are saying is that angular-material doesn't properly define it's module?

Comment: @michael_bitard: Kind of - it's basically a work around for the fact that Angular 1 wasn't really designed with ES6/TypeScript in mind (hence why they have their own module system). When you import an Angular 1 module, what's (generally) happening behind the scenes is that they're calling `angular.module("moduleName, [])` on the global `angular` object to set themselves up.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, so when I need to use angular-material in a template, I need to add `viewProviders: ['ngMaterial']` in the controller?

Comment: @michael_bitard: As far as I know, all you should have to do is import ngMaterial, then add it to your Angular application's dependencies (`angular.module("myApp", [ ngMaterial ])`). There aren't any other steps shown in [the getting started guide](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started), at least.

Comment: @michael_bitard: Although I don't know what the equivalent syntax is when you're using `ng-metadata`...

Comment: @michael_bitard: Ah, found it: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ ngMaterial ])`. So basically the same as what you had in the question, only you use the imported string rather than hard-coding it. This is important because if you  don't actually use a variable which you've imported, TypeScript will optimize out the import entire - i.e., if you do `import ngMaterial from "angular-material"` and then don't use the `ngMaterial` variable, the module won't get imported!

Comment: Yes but that's the main problem, if I `import ngMaterial from 'angular-material';` I get a `Module ''angular-material'' has no default export.` in my main.ts

Comment: @michael_bitard: Ah whoops, that might be due to the fact I have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` turned on in my TypeScript config - try using `import * as ngMaterial from "angular-material"` instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116477/discussion-between-michael-bitard-and-joe-clay).