# TS2307 when importing awesomplete on aurelia with typescript

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I am using aurelia-cli and typescript. I am trying to integrate awesomplete on my app. So I run: `npm install awesomplete --save`, edited `aurelia.json`:

```
{
    "name": "awesomplete",
    "path": "../node_modules/awesomplete",
    "main": "awesomplete"
}
```

and install the ts definition with `typings install dt~awesomplete --global --save`

on my ts file, I am importing it with `import * as awe from 'awesomplete';` but I get a `TS2307: Cannot find module 'awesomplete'`.
This is my first time using ts too so I think I am doing something wrong but cannot find what. Any hint, am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler probably can't find the definition file, as it's not enough to install it via `typings`.
As it states in [their FAQ](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md#user-content-module-resolutions):

> If you are using files in tsconfig.json, add the index file:

```
{
    "files": [
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

> If you are not using tsconfig.json, add as a reference to the top of
>   TypeScript files:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

Another (and better option) if you're using typescript version 2 and above is to use [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/~types) instead of typings:

```
npm install @types/awesomplete --save
```

Then you won't need to add anything to the tsconfig nor will you need to use the `reference` tags.
More on `@types`: [The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `export` statement in `typings/globals/awesomplete/index.d.ts`. This probably means that the authors of the typings did not consider the possibility of loading  awesomplete as a module, and intended it to be used only as plain script that defines some globals. So you can't import anything from it, but you can have `Awesomplete` and `AwesompleteOptions` available as globals if you include awesomplete typings in compilation as decsibed in Nitzan's answer to your question. In short, this compiles without any import:

```
let awe = new Awesomplete(document.getElementById('input-id'));
```

In other words, typings for awesomplete are what's used to be called [ambient typings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953848/what-are-ambient-typings-in-the-typescript-typings-tool) and could not be used in any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Awesomplete supports CommonJS module definition but not AMD (which is what the CLI uses). I believe the easiest would be "prepending" it in the aurelia.json file. Like this:

```
{
  "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
  "prepend": [
    "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
    "node_modules/awesomplete/awesomplete.js"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Or, you can load it using `<script>` tags, which always works for legacy libraries.

In both cases you don't have to import anything, you should use `Awesomplete` as a global function.