# TypeScript doesn't recognize JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying a simple class in typescript using Visual Studio 2015. Somehow, the TypeScript doesn't recognize getElementById! The following is the code I am using which I downloaded from another thread.

```
class TypeSearch {
searchKey = document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', ()    => this.search());

search() {
    alert("i am clicked");
  }
}
```

The error is "Can't resolve symbol getElementById"

Thanks

Comment: Try to get object first use var search = document.getElementById('search');

Comment: @tonydung what difference does that make?

Comment: This works for me, which is surprising given the bad formatting :-) Which version of the TypeScript tools do you use?

Comment: Maybe you didn't setup ambient definitions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953848/what-are-ambient-typings-in-the-typescript-typings-tool

Comment: Please include your `tsconfig.json` contents. If it doesn't exist, please run `tsc --init` at your project root and try compiling again.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the typings (type definition) for DOM.

You need to add the `dom` lib:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom"
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added it still it doesn't recognize getElementById!

Comment: Try to open your folder using VS Code to see if it works. I guess there is something else you need to configure in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully transpiled your typescript file into a Javascript file and caught the described error at runtime? If not, i.e. you get transpilation error, just add `declare var document: any`.